# What is the difference between useQuery and useLazyQuery in Apollo graphQL?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I was going through the documentation of Apollo React hooks.

And saw there are two queries hooks to use for which is `useQuery` and `useLazyQuery`

I was reading this page.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/

Can someone explain me what is the difference between them and in which case it should be used.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

When `useQuery` is called by the component, it triggers the query subsequently.

But when `useLazyQuery` is called, it does not trigger the query subsequently, and instead return a function that can be used to trigger the query manually.
It is explained on this page:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#manual-execution-with-uselazyquery

> When React mounts and renders a component that calls the `useQuery`
> hook, Apollo Client automatically executes the specified query.
> But what if you want to execute a query in response to a different event, such as a user clicking a button?
> The `useLazyQuery` hook is perfect for executing queries in response to events other than component rendering.
> This hook acts just like `useQuery`, with one key exception: when `useLazyQuery` is called, it does not immediately execute its associated
> query.
> Instead, it returns a function in its result tuple that you can call whenever you're ready to execute the query.

Comment: I was using "useLazyQuery" and I was sending variables from a state with the request and every time I change the state of the inputs the request executed every time the component mount, although I was using it onClick event.

Comment: @Sharif there should be a bug on how you use it (e.g inadvertantly execute the query function) or otherwise you may report issue https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues since this is not the case based on their documentation

Comment: you can create a new question and provide here so I can take a look? a minimal reproducible environment like codesandbox is deeply appreciated also.

Answer (score 26):

Suppose you have a component where you call useQuery, then as soon as the component mounts, useQuery runs and the data is fetched from the server.
But if you use useLazyQuery in that component instead of useQuery, query doesn't run and data isn't fetched when component mounts. Instead you can run the query based on your requirement, say after clicking a button. Example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/client';

function DelayedQuery() {
  const [dog, setDog] = useState(null);
  const [getDog, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_DOG_PHOTO);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading ...</p>;

  if (data && data.dog) {
    setDog(data.dog);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {dog && <img src={dog.displayImage} />}
      <button onClick={() => getDog({ variables: { breed: 'bulldog' } })}>
        Click me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here, as soon as you click the button, then only the query runs and data is fetched and the image is displayed. But if you had used useQuery instead, before clicking the button (i.e when the component mounts), the data would have been fetched and the image would have been displayed

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE:

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#improvements-due-to-brainkim-in-8875

useLazyQuery now returns a promise as of Apollo Client 3.5.0 (2021-11-08)

Answer (score 1):

Something that seems not to be spoken about that I just realize is that `useLazyQuery` doesn't read from the cache. This is somewhat similar to calling the `refetch` function returned from `useQuery`.

Comment: Yap, I was about 3 hours trying to figure out why my query is always fetching from API even with `cache-first` rule. I didn't see anything in the docs talking about it