# Refetching upon a button click in RTK Query does not trigger component update

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Hello all and thanks in advance.

Just to begin with, I am aware that weather data is not a suitable use case for RTK Query as it is always changing, I am using RTK Query in this case just for practicing purposes.
I want to refetch weather data upon a button click but the component is not being updated, however I can see that the `requestId` is indeed changing when clicking the refresh button and that data is being retrieved, by checking the console.
I am doing the refetch as in the example that can be found in the official docs:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/cache-behavior#re-fetching-on-demand-with-refetchinitiate

I am also wondering if it would be more suitable to use useLazyQuery and its `trigger` function instead...

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery

...but if so, what should I take into account in order to decide if I use useQuery or useLazyQuery?

```
    import {
  IonButton,
  IonButtons,
  IonCard,
  IonCol,
  IonContent,
  IonGrid,
  IonHeader,
  IonPage,
  IonRow,
  IonTitle,
  IonToolbar,
} from "@ionic/react";
import styles from "./Tab1.module.css";
import { RefreshOutline } from "react-ionicons";
import { Geolocation } from "@capacitor/geolocation";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { RootState } from "../app/store";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useGetCurrentPositionWeatherQuery } from "../services/weather";
import { setQueryCoord } from "../app/coordQuerySlice";
import TestSkeleton from "../components/TestSkeleton";

const Tab1: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const coordQueryState = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.coordQuery);
  const {
    requestId,
    refetch,
    data: weatherData,
    isLoading,
  } = useGetCurrentPositionWeatherQuery(
    {
      lat: coordQueryState.lat,
      lon: coordQueryState.lon,
      appid: "xxxx",
    },
    { skip: coordQueryState.skip }
  );

  const setCurrentPosition = async () => {
    const data = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
    const {
      coords: { latitude: latFetched },
      coords: { longitude: lonFetched },
    } = data;
    dispatch(setQueryCoord({ lat: latFetched, lon: lonFetched, skip: false }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentPosition();
  }, []);

  function refreshCurrentPositionHandler() {
    refetch();
  }

  console.log(requestId);
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar className={styles["ion-toolbar-dashboard"]}>
          <IonTitle className="ion-margin-bottom" size="large">
            Dashboard
          </IonTitle>
          <IonButtons slot="end">
            <IonButton>
              <RefreshOutline
                onClick={refreshCurrentPositionHandler}
                color={"black"}
                height="35px"
                width="35px"
                cssClasses={styles.refreshOutline}
              />
            </IonButton>
          </IonButtons>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <>{!weatherData && <TestSkeleton />}</>
        {weatherData && (
          <>
            <IonGrid>
              <IonRow style={{ margin: "10px" }}>
                <IonCol className="ion-text-center">
                  <h1 style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}>
                    Here's your location based weather
                  </h1>
                </IonCol>
              </IonRow>
            </IonGrid>
            <IonGrid>
              <IonCard>
                <IonRow>
                  <IonCol className="ion-text-center">test content 1</IonCol>
                </IonRow>
                <IonRow>
                  <IonCol className="ion-text-center">test content 2</IonCol>
                </IonRow>
                <IonRow>
                  <IonCol className="ion-text-center">test content 3</IonCol>
                </IonRow>
                <IonRow>
                  <IonCol></IonCol>
                  <IonCol></IonCol>
                </IonRow>
                <IonRow>
                  <IonCol></IonCol>
                </IonRow>
                <IonRow>
                  <IonCol></IonCol>
                </IonRow>
                <IonRow>
                  <IonCol></IonCol>
                </IonRow>
              </IonCard>
            </IonGrid>
          </>
        )}
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Tab1;
```

Comment: Actually I was just illuminated with the fact that I am using the wrong condition for rendering the content, it must be `isFetching` since `weatherData` is always true. Nevertheless, It would be great if someone can explain the part about when using useQuery and useLazyQuery, regarding refetch() and trigger() functions, thanks!

Comment: thanks alot brother.
You've fixed my problem :). I was stuck in same issue.
anyway you can  check difference here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63681650/what-is-the-difference-between-usequery-and-uselazyquery-in-apollo-graphql

Comment: So glad to have helped you brother! ;)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm not allowed to leave a comment yet, so I'll try to answer you question regarding `useLazyQuery` vs `useQuery` here:

`useQuery` - got triggered on render. Retriggered on params change. Returns data from cache if the cache has some valid data. `refetch` allows to ignore cache, and forces to make a real API call. `refetch` has no query params, so you'll need to pass them to initial hook call.

`useLazyQuery` - got triggered firstly on `trigger` call, expecting the query params to be passed to `trigger`, and by default will do a real API call. To get the cached data first (if exists) - you'll need to pass the `preferCacheValue` param to the `trigger` function as the second param.

So the "rule of thumb" will be to use
`useQuery` by default to fetch data on the component mount, use `refetch` when you want to make a real API call ignoring the cache.

`useLazyQuery` - for cases like yours, when you want to make a call only later (ignoring the render stage) calling the "trigger" on some event (like a button click), and remember about the `preferCacheValue` option for a case when you have a chance to have the response already cached - this will allow making response feels instantaneous.

In our case - `useLazyQuery` is MUCH relevant, due to you can avoid all that `setCurrentPosition` => `dispatch` => `useSelector` stuff, and pull all that logic just in click handler, where you'll be able to fetch `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` and pass coordinates to `trigger` function, that where relevant to the click time, not to the time when the component was rendered.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Eugene! now I understand the difference :D