# RTK Query how to update query state

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a route where i fetch all categories

```js
getAllCategoriesAdmin: builder.query({
       query: () => 'categories/allAdmin',
       providesTags: ['CategoriesAdmin']
    })
```

Then I get categories data from data refactored part of ***useGetAllCategoriesAdminQuery***

`const { isLoading, isError, data = {} } = useGetAllCategoriesAdminQuery();`

Now I want to implement search field where I want to update that data part with new data in other words when I create new route

```js
getAllCategoriesAdminSearch: builder.query({
        query: () => 'categories/allAdminSearch',
        providesTags: ['CategoriesAdmin'],
    })
```

Is there any way that I can reupdate data part from ***useGetAllCategoriesAdminQuery*** so I dont have to make another data from ***useGetAllCategoriesAdminSearchQuery***

`const { data = {} } = useGetAllCategoriesAdminSearchQuery();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refetching upon a button click in RTK Query does not trigger component update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71231118/refetching-upon-a-button-click-in-rtk-query-does-not-trigger-component-update)

Comment: is that what you are asking? useGetAllCategoriesAdminSearchQuery({foo: "bar:})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get your question completely but I'm assuming you have a query API and you need the search query for this API. I hope this helps you.

there are many ways to re-fetch the data:

1:
I think your API should support some query params for searches like this:

```
getAllCategoriesAdmin: builder.query({
       query: (searchInput) => `categories/allAdmin/?search=${searchInput}`,
       providesTags: ['CategoriesAdmin']
    })
```

RTK query creates a cache key base on query URL and params so if you change the search input it will automatically create a new request and fetch the data.

2:
another way is using `invalidateTags` for example if you have a mutaion query you can invalidate the tags in this case `CategoriesAdmin` and that causes the RTK clear the cache for corresponding query and refech the data.

3:
`refetch` function. every useHookQuery in RTK has a re-fetch function that you can assign it to your search event for re-fetching the new data.

```
const { refetch, isLoading, isError, data = {} } = useGetAllCategoriesAdminQuery();
```